# Deleted data rows reappearing when restarting .exe

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio

In visual studio 2015 community: 'windows forms application (visual basic)'

For my question I created a simple [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzHU1.png).
I added a service based database: "BusinessDatabase.mdf"
In this database I created a table: "Customers" with the following attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
    (
        [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
        [Name] TEXT NULL
    )
```

Form code:

```
Public Class Form
    Private Sub Add_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_button.Click
        Dim WorkRow As DataRow = BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers.NewRow()
        WorkRow(1) = "John Doe "
        BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers.Rows.Add(WorkRow)

        Me.Validate()
        Me.CustomersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Update(Me.BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Delete_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete_button.Click
        BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers)

    End Sub
End Class
```

I can add rows to the table just fine. When I exit the form and restart the .exe in the debug folder the data is still there as intended.

But when I try to delete rows from the table, exit the form and restart the .exe in the debug folder the deleted rows just reappear. I want them to stay deleted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the clear method that will remove the rows form the DataTable in memory but not back on the SQL Server file. You need to call the update on the Datatable adaptor after the clear statement. Try the following:

*Edited answer - The clear method just clears the rows in memory. to actually delete them you need to mark them as DELETED and then update the datasource see revised code below*

```
Private Sub Delete_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Delete_button.Click
    'BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers.Clear()
    For Each rw As DataRow In Me.BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers.rows
        rw.Delete()
    Next
    CustomersTableAdapter.Update(Me.BusinessDatabaseDataSet.Customers)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried your solution before. But oddly it doesn't work.

Comment: . 

You are right. The clear method just removes the rows from memory. You need to mark the rows as deleted so when you update the database the rows are marked to be deleted.

You can do this with the delete method for each row see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.delete(v=vs.110).aspx